# Which design pattern to use for multiple Interfaces with different behaviour

Tags: c#, java, design-patterns, command-pattern

I have a one Command Interface like this,

```
public interface ICommand{
     public abstract Object execute(List<Inputs> inputs);
}
```

Now I have A command for other type of complex Executions so I came up with the new Command Interface

```
public interface IComplexCommand {
  public abstract Object execute(ComplexObjects obj);
}
```

I invoke the commands from the properties file which is done inside a static initializer block of CommandFactory. My Factory method to Invoke looks like this.

```
ICommand cmd= CommandFactory.getInstance().getCommand("LoopElements");
// loopElements is the key in properties file to load my com.test.my.LoopElements
// to call execute of IComplex command it will not work because I have to typecase
// this I want to avoid.
```

Now I have a issue like when I get the Command I do not want to typecase the Command depending on Interface but I would like to have it understood at runtime,

Can anyone please help me in better designing this. I tried to google but I was not able to get any proper answer because the question is very specific.

Comment: Are you looking for [overloading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa691131.aspx)?

Comment: Actually I was thinking of having 2 CommandFactories, its not overloading but its somekind of polymorphism , I have to have ParentInterface to handle this.. I am confused little.

Comment: interfaces don't have behaviour... and i think you are looking for the Strategy pattern

Comment: @MarcoForberg is right. And make the parameter as a subclass type. I would make it  public abstract Object execute(Object inputs)

Comment: If I am correct, in Strategy Pattern,you  have multiple concrete Classes implementing a Interface, but in my case I have multiple interfaces and multiple classes. So I want to get the correct Class with Correct Interface type.

Comment: @Neron : I though of making it Object execute(Object... inputs), but its not the proper design.

Comment: @chaosguru U can always use "insteadof" inside the method but u are right. It is not a good one. Maybe u can use Java template like: <T> execute(<T> inputs)

Comment: Is there any restriction not to define a factory method for `IComplexCommand` interface such as `getComplexCommand`?

Comment: @Imran: No its not but all my commands are in a properties file and are loaded in a CommandMap at startup so how do I understand different commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest not to go for any Command factories. Command pattern actually lets you parameterize your request object. So you can create different type of command object for your easy and complex command scenario, and then you can execute them based on your command type you retrive from property file.
This is what i would do following command pattern, see if it helps:

```
public interface IOperations
{
    void PerformOperations();
}
public class EasyOperations : IOperations
{
   public void PerformOperations()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Do easy operations here");
    }
}
public class ComplexOperations : IOperations
{
    public void PerformOperations()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Do complex operations here");
    }
}

public interface ICommand
{
    void Execute();
}

public class EasyCommand : ICommand
{
    IOperations opn;
    public EasyCommand(IOperations opn)
    {
        this.opn=opn;
    }
    public void Execute()
    {
        opn.PerformOperations();
    }
}

 public class ComplexCommand : ICommand
{
    IOperations opn;
    public ComplexCommand(IOperations opn)
    {
        this.opn=opn;
    }
    public void Execute()
    {
        opn.PerformOperations();
    }
}   

public class OperationsPerformer
{
    IDictionary<string, ICommand> commands = new Dictionary<string, ICommand>();
    public OperationsPerformer()
    {
        commands.Add("easy", new EasyCommand(new EasyOperations()));
        commands.Add("complex",new ComplexCommand(new ComplexOperations()));
    }
    public void perform(string key)
    {
        if (commands[key] != null)
        {
            ICommand command = commands[key];
            command.Execute();
        }            
    }

}


public class Client
{
    public static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        OperationsPerformer performer = new OperationsPerformer();
        performer.perform("easy");
        performer.perform("complex");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

output:

Do easy operations here
Do complex operations here

Answer (score 0):

you could design it this way:

```
public interface ICommand
{
    public Object execute();
}

public class Command : ICommand
{
    List<Input> inputs;

    public void setInputs(List<Input> inputs)
    {
        this.inputs = inputs;
    }

    public Object execute()
    {
        // do something
    }
}

public class ComplexCommand : ICommand
{
    ComplexObjects inputs;

    public void setInputs(ComplexObjects inputs)
    {
        this.inputs = inputs;
    }

    public Object execute()
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Objects of both classes can be treated as `ICommand` objects so client code can call `execute()` and does not need to care for the concrete class behind the interface.

Comment: How would the client set the inputs if there is no method defined in the interface `ICommand`?

Comment: the inputs should be passed to the factory that takes their type to decide with kind of command to return. or just be defining methods with different parameters in the factory